# Why do SQL connection leave parameters in?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

While coding with sqlite everytime i always had the exact number of parameters and when i executed the query i always had 0 parameters after it. I kept using the cmd object and it worked fine.

Now while porting to use sql server (2008) my SqlConnection has parameters left over from a successful command. Why? I seem to be able to create tables without the problem (then again i may have use a clone of an empty cmd since i use recursion). Does SqlCommand always leave the parameters in after a query? This always breaks the following query unless i do parameter.clear().

Should i create a new SqlCommand object? or use parameter.clear() each time? I'm somewhat confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it leaves those there - you never told it otherwise.

What if you need to call the same SqlCommand hundreds of times in a row - do you want to keep re-creating all the parameters after each call?? Doesn't make a lot of sense to me....

My advice: use one SqlCommand per "command" or "query" you want to execute and set up its parameters as needed. I wouldn't "recycle" a single SqlCommand for a dozen different queries... just create a new one! That's definitely not an expensive operation.

Comment: What do you do in a function with several queries that can not be one long statement with several ';'? Do you make a cmd for each of them? Right now i am doing .clone() before each query for the moment.

Comment: Yes, I would have one SqlCommand for each "step" or statement, and just keep setting the new parameter values for each time you need to call those. Seems easier and cleaner than having a single SqlCommand and cloning that....

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's up to the provider whether or not it clears the parameter list each time you execute the command. Personally, I think the `SqlCommand` way makes more sense, because then I can do something like this:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SomeSprocName", ...);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "some string";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.Int);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters["@param2"].Value = i;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

That is, I can execute the same command over-and-over in a loop and only have to change the parameters that are actually different.

If you're executing a totally different command, then I would say it probably makes sense to just create another instance of the command object. It wouldn't *hurt* to call `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` and re-add the new parameters, but there are other properties on the command object that can affect the execution (e.g. `CommandType`, `CommandTimeout`, etc) and if you're executing a whole new command, it makes more sense to start from scratch.

Comment: Also, if I am not mistaken, keeping the parameters improves performance.